# Spoon ETL how to change the values

Tags: etl, pentaho-spoon

I want to transform two values in a column with spoon.

I have a value "1" in the column gender and want to change this to the value "Male"
And I have a value "0" in the column gender and want to change this to the value "Female"

As you could see the input is a csv file and the output will be a excel file. 
Which steps do i need to make the transformation of gender?

[Steps of ETL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgV5E.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use Value Mapper Step in transformation. This will allow you to do this.